# Transparent proxy through another proxy using HTTP CONNECT

Tags: http, https, proxy

I have a few legacy clients that don't "speak" HTTPS which I've connected to an upstream server serving content only over HTTPS using nginx as a reverse proxy. This is the flow:

(1) client -> (2) nginx:80 redirects to https -> (3) upstream server

The problem now is in front of (3) there is a forwarding proxy I have to go through, proxy which does HTTPS over HTTP Connect and I have a hard time finding a way to somehow bridge (or replace completely) nginx over HTTP Connect:

(1) client -> **(2) nginx:80 redirects to https ->**  (3) proxy HTTP CONNECT  -> (4) upstream

Any ideas what should go in or instead of the **bold** component ?

I've looked at tinyproxy but that expects HTTP Connect directly (which nginx does not support) and squid which I cannot figure out how to configure to do HTTPS over HTTP CONNECT.

I am essentially looking for a way to bridge http to https through a proxy, please ignore any product names and feel free to suggest anything  - including code samples. The clients as well as the server are part of my application.

Comment: Your question is not related to programming and is offtopic here.

Comment: It is very much on topic since it relates to web architectures and programming (HTTP protocol). Web is more than HTML, please change your vote.

Comment: You are asking about configuring some servers or proxies. This question is clearly off-topic. Indeed there exist many nginx-related  questions on StackOverflow and most of them are off-topic as well (and downvoted as such).

Comment: How about now, does the last paragraph make more clear the scope of my question ?

Comment: I doubt. As you can see from lack of answers, people are either not interested in the question or the question is outside of their competence set. Thus asking on more appropriate site would simply give you more chance to get an answer.